# How to provide updated data to D3.data()?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using D3 to draw a chart:

```
function render(mydata) {
    const svg = d3.select(domSVG);
    svg
        .selectAll('g')
        .data(mydata)
        .join(...
```

This works fine and the chart is drawn correctly.  However if I want to change the data, I am not able to get it to pick up any modifications.  It will pick up additions and removals, creating and deleting DOM nodes as necessary, but it won't pick up any modifications:

```
mydata = [
    { name: 'Item A', value: 100 },
];

// The initial render works fine.
render(mydata);

// But I can't change the data!
mydata[0].value = 500;
render(mydata); // renders 100, not 500
```

I tried putting a `console.log()` in the update function to work out why:

```
...
svg
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(mydata)
    .join(
        enter => ...,
        update => update.text(d => console.log(d.data) || 'test'),
```

And this logs the *old* value (100) even after I have set the value to 500 and passed the updated array to `data()`.

My understanding was that when you passed the updated object into `data()`, it would figure out which elements are new, removed and need to be updated.  I can get it to successfully pick up new entries and create new nodes, and remove old ones, and it correctly calls `update()` for the elements that remain present, but the data passed to the callback functions inside `update()` is from the old array, but I want it passed content from the new array I gave to `data()`!

I have the real code running on a timer, and every second it passes a new value to `data()` (verified by using `console.log(mydata)` just before the `data()` call) and it just "updates" the items with the original content.  The nodes never get changed again after `enter()` has initially created the DOM node, even though `update()` is being called for them - it just can't make any changes because it's always running with the first array ever passed to `data()`, it never sees any of the subsequent arrays passed to `data()`.

How do I tell `data()` to pass its parameter through so the callbacks use the new value instead of reusing values from the first ever `data()` call?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the problem was I had multiple child elements - each element in the `data()` array was being turned into `<g><path/><path/></g>` (one node with two child nodes) and this has to be handled a bit specially.

It seems that in this case the data is bound to the initial node (the `<g>` in this case) but not fully passed down to child nodes.  It seems you have to use `select()` to identify specific nodes that need to be additionally bound to the source data, as this function has some extra logic to extend the data binding to the child nodes.

Once I changed my update function to this, it worked:

```
update => update
    .select('path.child1class')  // a select() is mandatory!
    .text(...
```

Then everything worked, the updated data flowed through as expected.

I was not able to get this to work if I used the `select()` in the `enter()` function though (as it matched no elements and so no child nodes were ever added under the `<g/>`).  I could only use it in `update()`.